# Discord.js awaitReactions on message fetch by id not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem with "message.awaitReactions" from a message that was send by my bot a long ago.

Here's the code :

```
let channel = client.guilds.cache
    .get("<guild_id>")
    .channels.cache.get("<channel_id>");

  channel.messages
    .fetch(<message_id_that_was_sent_a_long_ago_by_my_bot>)
    .then((message) => {
      message
        .awaitReactions(
          (reaction, user) =>
            reaction.emoji.name == "" || reaction.emoji.name == ""
        )
        .then((collected) => {
          console.log("collected", collected);
          if (collected.first().emoji.name == "") {
            user.setNickname(" " + user.username);
          } else {
          //TODO
          }
          // reaction.remove(user);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          message.reply("No reaction, operation canceled");
        });
    });
```

The problem is that nothing append when the user add reactions on the message and I don't know why :(

Anybody knows why ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `.fetch("123")` or `.fetch(123)`

Comment: I'm using config.id_message witch is property of config.json and It's "123", the message is fetched because i can log it just before the awaitReactions. It's the awaitReactions that is not triggered

Comment: When is that posted code run?

Comment: It's in 

client.on("ready", () => {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 15000 })` would wait 15s for reactions, then enter the `.then().`
You have nothing specified, so it will never enter the `.then()`.

What you should use instead is:

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == "" || reaction.emoji.name == ""
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter);
collector.on('collect', (messageReaction, user) => { 
    console.log(`Collected ${messageReaction.emoji.name}`) 
    if (r.emoji.name == "") {
        messageReaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user.id).then(member => member.setNickname(" " + user.username));
    } else {
        // TODO
    }
    // reaction.remove(user);
});
```

Or use the event messageReactionAdd, you would still need to fetch the message for this event to fire.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => {
     if(messageReaction.message.id != '<message_id_that_was_sent_a_long_ago_by_my_bot>') return;
     if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "") {
         messageReaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user.id).then(member => member.setNickname(" " + user.username));
     }
     // reaction.remove(user);
})
client.on('ready', () => {
     let channel = client.guilds.cache
         .get("<guild_id>")
         .channels.cache.get("<channel_id>");
     channel.messages.fetch('<message_id_that_was_sent_a_long_ago_by_my_bot>');
}
```